# Shabbos and Later Davening (Prayer)

Tags: shabbat, zemanim, shacharis-morning-prayer

Why on Shabbos do most people daven (pray) later than usual? (I seek an halachic answer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Ramah** poskins based on a **Mordecai** in Shabbos in the name of **Reb Hai Gaon** on the posuk

> וּבְיוֹם הַשַּׁבָּת שְׁנֵי כְבָשִׂים בְּנֵי שָׁנָה תְּמִימִם וּשְׁנֵי עֶשְׂרֹנִים סֹלֶת מִנְחָה בְּלוּלָה בַשֶּׁמֶן וְנִסְכּוֹ:‏

He says since during the weekday *Korbon Tamid* it says the word **בבוקר** and here it says **וביום השבת** it implies that on Shabbos we should daven later. The **Mishnah Berurah** argues and says Based on *Rashi* In *Meggilah* (*Daf:Chuf Gimmel*) that on Shabbos you should prefrably also Daven Vasikin and he ends off of course adding even according to the Ramah you would still have to make *Zman Kriyas Shemah*.

Comment: can you add a source for the Ramah and Mishna Berurah?

Comment: That _pasuk_ is talking about _musaf_. Where do we see from it that _shacharis_ should be later than usual?

Comment: Maybe getting a longer night's sleep is considered oneg shabbat?